# How to loop over a range of datetime in order to plot a graph?

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to loop over a range of datetime values in order to use it as my x-axis in a matplotlib Graph in Python.

Here's my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    datetime(2022, 6, 21, 0),
    datetime(2022, 6, 21, 1),
    datetime(2022, 6, 21, 2),
    datetime(2022, 6, 21, 3),
    ...
    datetime(2022, 6, 23, 10),
    datetime(2022, 6, 23, 11),
    datetime(2022, 6, 23, 12),
    ...
    datetime(2022, 6, 25, 21),
    datetime(2022, 6, 25, 22),
    datetime(2022, 6, 25, 23)
]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, ..., 168]

# plotting the points 
plt.plot(dates, y)
plt.show()
```

How can I use a loop in order to avoid entering datetimes manually ?
Imagine for example that I want to use hourly datetime for a whole week, this would mean 168 datetimes into `dates = []` . Not efficient at all !

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dates = [datetime(2022,6,21,0) + timedelta(hours=h) for h in range(168)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime(2022, 6, 21, 0)
end_date = datetime(2022, 6, 25, 23)

hour = timedelta(hours=1)
days = []

while start_date <= end_date:
    days.append(start_date)
    start_date += hour

print(days)
```